# How to usemin external files using grunt-usemin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

How to download external files and to concat, using grunt-usemin?

```
<!-- build:js release/all.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.carouFredSel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.domain.com.br/scripts/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.domain.com.br/scripts/jquery.slideshow.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And useminPrepare show:

```
concat:
  { generated: 
   { files: 
      [ { dest: '.tmp/concat/release/all.min.js',
          src: 
           [ 'web/scripts/jquery.js',
             'web/scripts/jquery.carouFredSel.js',
             'web/http:/cdn.domain.com.br/scripts/jquery.cycle.js',
             'web/http:/cdn.domain.com.br/scripts/jquery.slideshow.js'] } ] } }
```

The two last files don't add on my all.min.js because are external files. How to include?

Comment: If you really need the files to be concatenated in your own file. Dont use CDN and keep them locally...

Comment: OK, but how to download external files and replace HTML references using Grunt?

Comment: Visit the url in browser save it inside ur scripts directory with others and replace all occurrences in your source with the relative file path and in Grunt configuration.

Comment: Or you can use bower.